# How to make a object accessible through all files in C#

Tags: c#, class, object

I have a class object which i want to access in all the files in c# project
Ofcourse i dont want 'static' qualifiers because i want to serialize this object finally.

Comment: Please give an example of what you're trying to do. Usually when a developer talks about "files" like you are, it means he doesn't understand C# at all.

Answer (score 4):

Make the class `public`.

You should then be able to create instances wherever you need.

If you want a single instance to be accessible throughout your entire project, I would suggest checking out the [Singleton pattern](http://dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternSingleton.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to you to use only one instance of this class - use one of the most popular pattern **Singleton**:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

```
using System;

public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This sample - yes, you can find in the referenced article **Multithreaded Singleton**